# Scala convert string between two charsets

Tags: scala, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a misformed UTF-8 string consisting that should be written "Michèle Huà" but outputs as "MichÃ¨le HuÃ"

According to this table it is a problem between Windows-1252 and UTF-8
http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

How do I make conversion?

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromBytes("MichÃ¨le HuÃ".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1").mkString
res25: String = MichÃÂ¨le HuÃ

scala> scala.io.Source.fromBytes("MichÃ¨le HuÃ".getBytes(), "UTF-8").mkString
res26: String = MichÃ¨le HuÃ

scala> scala.io.Source.fromBytes("MichÃ¨le HuÃ".getBytes(), "Windows-1252").mkString
res27: String = MichÃƒÂ¨le HuÃƒ
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually have the complete string there, due to an unfortunate issue with one character printing blank.  "Michèle Huà" when encoded as UTF-8 but read as Windows-1252 is actually "MichÃ¨le HuÃ ", where that last character is 0xA0 (but typically pastes as 0x20, a space).

If you can include that character, you can convert successfully.

```
scala> fixed = new String("MichÃ¨le HuÃ\u00A0".getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8")
fixed: String = Michèle Huà
```